# is there a way to put all my list into one cell in my CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

is there a way to put all my list into one cell in my CSV file? The reason for doing this is because the variable belongs to a single data.

```
row1 = [(1.1603180714482149, 103.9129638389025),
 (1.160308848641466, 103.912935217908),
 (1.1602761166689228, 103.91294562159307),
 (1.1602853394755797, 103.91297424258724),
 (1.1603180714482149, 103.9129638389025)]

# This is the code that i ran

from csv import writer
def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    
# Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
       
 # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
       
 # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

append_list_as_row('xxx.csv', row1)
```

below here isn't a code, i am just trying to show the result clearly

```
The result i got was
A                                         B
(1.1603180714482149, 103.9129638389025)   (1.160308848641466, 103.912935217908)

i am trying to get 

A
(1.1603180714482149, 103.9129638389025), (1.160308848641466, 103.912935217908), xxxx,xxx,xx
```

Comment: A more structured data format that supports nested lists such as JSON would be more suitable to your needs than CSV, unless you're stuck with CSV because some API you use requires it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `writerow()`, each list element is a separate fields in the CSV. If you want everything in one field, you need to make it a single list element. So put `list_of_elem` inside another list.

```
csv_writer.writerow([list_of_elem])
```

Note that when it does this it will add another set of `[]` around the field, since it's a list.